# kotlin AlertDialog Custom null

Tags: android, kotlin, illegalstateexception

I want to use AlertDialog by kotlin, and this is just a demo. 
However, this doesn't works. When I push `positiveButton`, it returns 
`java.lang.IllegalStateException`

Can anyone fix this error. Here is the code

```
override fun onClick(view: View?) {
    val customLayout = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.component_time_table_dialog, null)
    AlertDialog.Builder(this).apply {
        setTitle("QUESTION")
        setView(customLayout)
        setPositiveButton("ACCEPT", DialogInterface.OnClickListener { dialogInterface, which ->
            Toast.makeText(mContext, subjectName.text.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        })
        setNegativeButton("REJECT", null)
        create()
        show()
    }
    Toast.makeText(this, " Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
}
```

**component_time_table_dialog.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/subjectName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="SubjectName"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: your code is working fine for me

Comment: it does work. can you attach full exception?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you do the following:

```
val alertBuilder = AlertDialog.Builder(this)

alertBuilder.setMessage("MESSAGE")

alertBuilder.setTitle("QUESTION")

alertBuilder.setPositiveButton("ACCEPT") { dialog, which ->
    Toast.makeText(this, "TOAST", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
}

alertBuilder.setNegativeButton("REJECT") { dialog, which ->
    // ...
}

val alertDialog = alertBuilder.create()
alertDialog.show()
```